# How to specify paths in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have set up this Cucumber feature in 'spree_fit_card/new_gift_card.feature`:

```
@gift-card
Feature: access gift cards
  As a general user
  I will be able to place an order for a gift card

  Scenario: The gift card index page will redirect to /new
    When I am on the gift card page
    Then I will be redirected to the new gift card page
```

And in the `support/paths.rb`:

```
module NavigationHelpers
  def path_to(page_name)
    when /the gift card page/
      spree.gift_cards_path
    when /the new gift card page/
      spree.new_gift_card_path
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

And when we checkout `step_definitions/new_gift_card_steps.rb`:

```
When(/^I am on the gift card page$/) do
  pending
end

Then(/^I will be redirected to the new gift card page$/) do
  pending
end
```

Cucumber outputs:

```
$ zeus cucumber --tags @gift-card
Loading fixtures
Using the default profile...
@gift-card
Feature: access gift cards
  As a general user
  I will be able to place an order for a gift card

  Scenario: The gift card page will redirect to the new gift card page # features/spree_gift_card/new_gift_card.feature:6
    When I am on the gift card page                                 # features/spree_gift_card/new_gift_card.feature:7
      Ambiguous match of "I am on the gift card page":

      features/step_definitions/spree_gift_card/new_gift_cards_steps.rb:1:in `/^I am on the gift card page$/'
      cucumber-websteps-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/websteps/browsing_steps.rb:1:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'

      You can run again with --guess to make Cucumber be more smart about it
       (Cucumber::Ambiguous)
      -e:1:in `<main>'
      features/spree_gift_card/new_gift_card.feature:7:in `When I am on the gift card page'
    Then I will be redirected to the new gift card page              # features/step_definitions/spree_gift_card/new_gift_cards_steps.rb:5

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/spree_gift_card/new_gift_card.feature:6 # Scenario: The gift card page will redirect to the new gift card page
```

So I took Cucumber's suggestion into consideration and ran `zeus cucumber --tags @gift-card --guess`

```
Loading fixtures
Using the default profile...
@gift-card
Feature: access gift cards
  As a general user
  I will be able to place an order for a gift card

  Scenario: The gift card page will redirect to the new gift card page # features/spree_gift_card/new_gift_card.feature:6
    When I am on 'the gift card page'                                  # features/step_definitions/spree_gift_card/new_gift_cards_steps.rb:1
      TODO (Cucumber::Pending)
      ./features/step_definitions/spree_gift_card/new_gift_cards_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am on the gift card page$/'
      features/spree_gift_card/new_gift_card.feature:7:in `When I am on the gift card page'
    Then I will be redirected to the new gift card page              # features/step_definitions/spree_gift_card/new_gift_cards_steps.rb:5

1 scenario (1 pending)
2 steps (1 skipped, 1 pending)
0m0.016s
Cleaning up database
```

I'm glad that it passes with `--guess`, but I don't understand why its not passing without it. I think I've set it up right, but I obviously haven't. I'm using the [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) framework if it helps with Ruby on Rails version 3.2.17.

Answer (score 0):

Reason can be found back in the errors you're giving:

```
cucumber-websteps-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/websteps/browsing_steps.rb:1:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
```

shows that there is a "default" step, in browsing_steps.rb, which also matches with your test. That's the reason why you get this error. As you see, the matching is "less" than with your step, and that's the reason that "guess" works: it will chose automatically for the "best fitting" step definition.

Comment: Did my answer shed any light on your problem?